# How to show placeholder in dynamically created input field instead of name

Tags: html, vue.js

I have two input fields inside of a form and a button. When the user clicks the button more input fields are being generated dynamically. It works great but the problem is that my inputs show their name values and it looks like they are pre-populated, which is not what I want, I just want them to show the placeholders instead. How can I show the placeholders instead and not display the name value?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
    <input 
        v-model="shareholder.username" 
        :name="`shareholders[${index}][username]`" 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control input" 
        placeholder="Username"
    >
</div>
<div>
    <input 
        v-model="shareholder.investment" 
        :name="`shareholders[${index}][investment]`" 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control input" 
        placeholder="Investment"
    >
    <i 
        v-if="shareholder.dynamic" 
        class="fas fa-trash"  
        @click="deleteItem(index)"
    />
</div>
```

My data:

```
shareholders: [
    {
        investment: "Investment",
        username: "Username",
        dynamic: false
    },
],
```

and the way new fields are generated:

```
createNewPricedRoundShareholder() {
    this.shareholders.push({
        username: "Username",
        investment: "Investment",
        dynamic: true
    })
},
```

Comment: You can give a visual example for what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `.push` in your shareholders array, you are sending a populated data for `username` and `investment`, try to do your `.push` with empty values like this.

```
    createNewPricedRoundShareholder() {
      this.shareholders.push({
        username: "",
        investment: "",
        dynamic: true
      })
  },
```